# Terraform templatefile conditional statement to generate ansible inventory file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
// Terraform v0.14.9

# var.tf
variable "launch_zk" {
  type        = string
  description = "Whether to launch zookeeper or not"
  default     = false
}

# main.tf
resource "aws_instance" "zk_ec2" {
  count                = var.launch_zk ? var.zk_instance_count : 0
...
} 
 
# output.tf 
output "zk_ips" {
  description = "IPs of ZK instances"
  value = {
    for vm in aws_instance.zk_ec2 :
    vm.tags.Name => vm.private_ip
  }
}

resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventoryFile" {
  content = templatefile("ansible_inventory.tpl",
    {
      zk-private-ip     = var.zk_instance_count < 10 ? slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_ip, 0, 3) : slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_ip, 0, 5),
      zk-private-dns    = var.zk_instance_count < 10 ? slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns, 0, 3) : slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns, 0, 5),
    }
  )
  filename = "ansible_inventory"
}

# ansible_inventory.tpl
[zk_servers]
%{ for index, dns in zk-private-dns ~}
${zk-private-ip[index]} server_name=${dns}
%{ endfor ~}
```

This is what I am using and now I want to conditionally generate output file including ansible inventory file. It should include IP and DNS of zookeeper only if I am passing boolean true parameter to my "launch_zk" variable otherwise it should not print anything. Here I am not able to perform conditional statement in my output file and ansible template tpl file. Can someone tell me how can I get it working?

Here I will have to use multiple conditional statement like this but I am getting error given below

```
resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventoryFile" {
      content = templatefile("ansible_inventory.tpl",
        {
          zk-private-ip     = var.launch_zk ? var.zk_instance_count < 10 ? slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_ip, 0, 3) : slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_ip, 0, 5) : "",
          zk-private-dns    = var.launch ? var.zk_instance_count < 10 ? slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns, 0, 3) : slice(aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns, 0, 5) : "",
        }
      )
      filename = "ansible_inventory"
    }


# Error
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on output.tf line 67, in resource "local_file" "AnsibleInventoryFile":
  67:       zk-private-dns = var.launch_zk ? aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns : "",
    |----------------
    | aws_instance.zk_ec2 is empty tuple
    | var.launch_zk is "false"

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are tuple and string, respectively.
```

Comment: "I am not able to perform conditional statement" - it is not specific. Why you can't? What errors do you get? What did you try?

Comment: @Marcin, I updated my question with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html#result-types) explain, your condition must have **consistent types**:

> The two result values may be of any type, but they **must both be of the same type** so that Terraform can determine what type the whole conditional expression will return without knowing the condition value.

In your case you return a list, and string:

```
#                              ? list                              : string    
zk-private-dns = var.launch_zk ? aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns : ""
```

The easiest way to ensure consistent types is by having an **empty list**:

```
zk-private-dns = var.launch_zk ? aws_instance.zk_ec2.*.private_dns : []
```

This change may require further changes in your code to account for the empty list

Comment: Thanks .That was pretty easy. I should have read the error msg properly. Do you think there will be any changes required in ansible_inventory.tpl file or it will just output blank under "[zk_servers]" group

Comment: @user3847894 Not sure. I would just run it and see how it goes.

Comment: In my case I'm getting a tuple and a tuple which makes no sense.